# php multiple variable verifications

Tags: php, html, css

i need to verify 6 variables to see if they are empty, if so i want to somehow keep a record of which were empty so i can warn the user of my website which ones he still needs to fill with information. so far i can only warn him that he has fields to fill with this code:

```
if (empty($email) || empty($emailConf) || empty($password) || empty($passwordConf) || empty($firstname) || empty($lastname)){
$alert = "Every field needs to be filled with information!";
}
```

i also feel like this method is kinda unprofessional so if you guys have any ideas to make it better and also solve the problem i mentioned above feel free to suggest!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose your informations come from a POST form. If so do this.

```
<?php
$ok = true;
$invalid_fiels = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($value)) {
        $ok = false;
        $invalid_fields[] = $key;    
    }
}

if (!$ok)
    echo "Every field needs to be filled with information!";
?>
```

The array invalid_fields will contain all the invalid fields.

Comment: this method seems fine but how do i identify which ones where empy after this process? thanks

Comment: @aconstancio Please read the answer again. Hint: look at `$invalid_fields`

Comment: i get the invalid fields but they still aren't ready to be shown to the user since i only get its names and its names are not "treated".

what i wanted to do is for instance show a list like:

Empty fields:

Name
Age
Etc

but i cant just yet, all i can do is for instance: 
Empty fields:

txtName
txtAge
etc

Comment: Then browse this array and `echo` each invalid fields

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do what @Valentin Mercier suggests, using `array_filter`. By default `array_filter` deletes all empty values from the array, but you can invert that behavior using a callback, that returns `true` for an empty array entry. (Every value for which the callback function returns `true` is kept in the returned array.)

The main reason for using a loop or a filter function is that you can add or remove some inputs and the check will still work.

```
$emptyFields = array_filter( $_POST, function( $value ) {
    return empty( $value );
} );

if( !empty( $emptyFields ) ) {
    echo sprintf(
        'The following fields were missing: "%s"',
        implode( '", "', array_keys( $emptyFields ) )
    );
}
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: Epic answer, too bad I have reached my maximum number of upvotes today, I would have gladly upvoted this one.

Comment: id prefer array_diff_key ,well see my answer, thats how id do it.

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix Yes I saw your answer and you are using two function calls with two internal loops to achieve the same ;-)

Comment: @feeela true, but i doub't performance will be an issue ( between 1 internal loop, because that is really what the difference is ), id skip the function call to sprintf, as simple concatenation would do the same. yours i see 3 function calls an one loop, mine 2 function calls 2 loops, ( not counting implode and array_keys, and your empty ) - but now were splitting hairs

Comment: +1, because I said I would :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$values = array(
                'name' => 'name',
                'email' => 'email',
                'empty' => '',
                'null'  => null,
                'zero'  => 0,
                'strZero'=>'0'
        );

var_export( array_diff_key( $values, array_filter( $values ) ) );
```

outputs

```
array(
'empty' => '',
'null' => null,
'zero' => 0,
'strZero' => '0'
)
```

if you want just the names use array_keys() on the results and then you could implode(',', $keys).

```
var_export( implode(', ' , array_keys( array_diff_key( $values, array_filter( $values ) ) ) ) );
```

outputs

```
'empty, null, zero, strZero'
```

to explain,

array_filter() removes empty elements,
array_diff_key() returns an array containing all the keys in array1 that are not in array2
array_keys() returns only the keys in the array
implode(), implodes the array with a text seperator.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a nested `if` statement as such, this determines which are empty and tells the user

```
if (empty($email) || empty($emailConf) || empty($password) || empty($passwordConf) || empty($firstname) || empty($lastname)){
$alert = "Every field needs to be filled with information!";

if(empty($email)){$ErrorVariable = "Email is empty!";}

if(empty($emailConf)){$ErrorVariable = "EmailConf is empty!";}

//Do this for everything you don't want empty, if the field is not empty, the nested if statement won't get called
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

```
// Just for test ;)
$_POST = array(
    'email'     => 'foo',
    'emailConf' => '',
);

$required_fields = array('email', 'emailConf', 'password');
$empty_fields = array();

array_walk(
    $required_fields,
    function ($field) use ($empty_fields) {
        if(!isset($_POST[$field]) || trim($_POST[$field]) == ''){
            $empty_fields[] = $field;
        }
    }
);

if(!empty($empty_fields)) {
    echo 'The following fields where missing: ';
    echo implode(', ', $empty_fields);
}
```

Result:
`The following fields where missing: emailConf, password`

Answer (score -1):

Even if the best way is to check input *also* before submit (with javascript), to do what you want you already have necessary data:
The variables themselves indicate which of them is empty so:

```
$message=""; //initialize
if(empty($var1)) $message.="var1 is empty<br/>";
if(empty($var2)) $message.="var2 is empty<br/>";
...//And so on... 
echo $message;
```

You can style it better...

Comment: Don't bother about display/styling beforehand. At fist one should have a logic implemented, that validates the user input. The error message output should be handled separately. For example collecting all the empty fields (i.e. their names) in an array an use this array in the template.